# How do I create a checkmark in unicode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would think it would be:

```
"&#x2713;".encode(:unicode)
```

But I think this is not the correct usage of .encode.  And when I say:

```
"&#x2713;".encode('Unicode')
```

it cannot do the conversion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Ruby 1.9 (which has much better built-in encoding support), you can do this:

```
> checkmark = "\u2713"
# => "✓" 
> checkmark.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```